# Arcgis quantization parameters - Openlayers features

Tags: openlayers, arcgis

I'm calling to a Arcgis service using quantization parameters, so I get a compressed response for features geometries. The response is:

[image]

My problem is that I don't know how to draw these features in my map. When I don't use quantization parameters and I get regular coordinates for the features I can do it using Openlayers and the following code:

[image]

It seems that when I get compressed coordinates I have to use some kind of transformation in order to be able to draw the features in my map. In the response of the Arcgis service I get the following information,, but I don't know how to use it to transform the geometries into regular coordinates:

[image]

Thanks in advance...

Comment: The values in the coordinates, along with the scale and translate, look similar to a TopoJSON but with `rings` instead of `arcs`, so you would also need to handle relative coordinates.  It might be easier to use Esri's pbf format (which not compatible with OpenLayers) and `arcgisPbfDecode` (where the code https://github.com/rowanwins/arcgis-pbf-parser/blob/master/src/parser/EsriFeatureCollection.js suggests it supports `scale` and `translate`) to convert to a format which OpenLayers can handle https://codesandbox.io/s/vector-esri-forked-dsp783?file=/main.js